# Why isn't my custom cell button image updating to my array values?

Tags: swift

Basically I have my savedmusicarray and this downloaded url, if it is equal to nothing I want the image to be a checkmark so it says the user has downloaded the image if not it'll be the downloaded button.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    if savedMusicArray[arrayindex!.row].downloadedUrl != "" {
        self.downloadButon.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        self.downloadButon.setImage(UIImage(named: "download2"), for: .normal)
    }

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

import UIKit

class DownloadPopup: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var mainLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var songLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var startButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var popupView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var cancelButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupView()
    songLabel.text = songToDownload.name!
}
func setupView() {
    popupView.addRoundedCorners(radius: 10)
    startButton.layer.cornerRadius = startButton.frame.height / 2
    startButton.addBorder(color: .white, width: 1)
    cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = startButton.frame.height / 2
    cancelButton.addBorder(color: .white, width: 1)
    cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCancel), for: .touchUpInside)
    startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDownload), for: .touchUpInside)
    popupView.addBorder(color: .white, width: 1)
}
@objc func handleCancel() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
@objc func handleDownload() {
    let downloader = Downloader(self)
    let url = URL(string: songToDownload.url!)
    downloader.download(url: url!, index: arrayindex!)
}
```

}

Comment: After updating the image of a cell you have to reload the tableview and can you please upload VC code so I can check why it happens?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: i uploaded the code  @Abhishek Jadhav

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri basically how do i swithc a imagefor a certain indexpath.row if the file is downloaded

Comment: Where are you doing the network call from?

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri a custom downloader class, code is uploaded

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53879933/edit) the question with your code. Don't add them as answers.

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri it wasnt letting me

Comment: You should do the downloading part inside the cell and handle the result in the completion of your network call.

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri  the file downloads and its saved into the array but the button i want to update if it is downloaded? make sense

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code button image change code in handleDownload function or in cellForRowAt. and in handleDownload function, if you want to get a particular cell then write like this.

//From this, you can get particular music which is the list on the cell

```
let music = savedMusicArray[sender.tag]
```

//From here you get the particular row to change the image of a button

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
let cell= self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MusicLibraryCell
```

Then you can change the button image of the particular row and reload the rows or reload the tableview.
Otherwise, Button change image code you can write in `cellForRowAt` but you have to reload the tableview from button action or after completion of downloaded image.

Comment: and with this here, itll be able to save the image selection?

Comment: You can change the image, in this function after you downloaded music or in a cell, I will give you hint or 80% answer, because I don't from where you called downloadURL function, But you have to do in this way only.

Comment: i called that fucntion within the custom download class i have created. if i out it in cell for row at , its based off the class song setup so its all references and  replaces all the varibles right?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to create extra variables what you created in VC.

Comment: Then you have to check you music downloaded code, I gave you answer for button image changing is not working.